# Code 500 Internal Server Error on SendAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, api

I'm trying to send the key and values to the API Url but when the SendAsync throw me the error 500 and I test it on the Postman and is work fine... what I'm doing wrong? I'm thinking is the keyValues I'm constructing and sending to the send idk...(I'm new at this(API)).

```
var token = await GetToken();
        RequestModel requestModel = new RequestModel(requestViewModel);
        string Baseurl = "https://example.api.com";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", token));
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/example.api/api/test/individual/get");

            var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("SolicitantData", null));
            keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Name", requestViewModel.SolicitantDataView.Name));
            keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("MiddleInitial", requestViewModel.SolicitantDataView.MiddleInitial));
            keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("LastName", requestViewModel.SolicitantDataView.LastName));
            keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("LastName2", requestViewModel.SolicitantDataView.LastName2));
            keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("NickName", ""));
            keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("SSN", requestViewModel.SolicitantDataView.SSN));
            keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("BirthDate", requestViewModel.SolicitantDataView.BirthDate.ToString()));
            keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("EmailAddress", requestViewModel.SolicitantDataView.EmailAddress));
            keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("DriverLicense", ""));
            keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("DeathDate", ""));
            keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Addresses", "[]"));
            keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("PhoneNumbers", "[]"));
            keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("TerminalId", requestViewModel.TerminalId.ToString()));
            keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("OGPATGNumber", ""));
            keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("OGPCorrelationID", ""));
            keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Source", requestViewModel.Source));
            keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("UserId", ""));
            keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("IndividualId", ""));
            keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("SendByEmail", requestViewModel.SendByEmail.ToString()));


            request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request); // <----- Code 500 here.
  }
     return View();
  }
```

Comment: You will do well by learning how to use a try-catch

Comment: @JonathanPadilla What error did you get back from the Exception in the try catch?

Comment: How are you _"testing it on Postman"_? With the data payload you have above? Realistically, nobody here can test this for you. You're getting an error response (http 500) based on what you're sending somewhere.

Comment: @EdSF I already fix it, The problem is I can't provide to much information cuz the url for example is a real federal api service and I'm not authorized to provide the correct information I'm sorry about that. But I fix it reworking on the models, the way the other developer design the structure of the code no was the good way apparently. Thank you for your response and thanks the others too!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(keyValues),Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(content);
```